# laplace step function $H(π-t)(\sin(t))^2$

Tags: laplace-transform

How to calculate the laplace transformation of $H(π-t)(\sin(t))^2$ ? I know that I have to use $\sin^2(t)= 1/2(1-2\cos(2t))$ but i am stuck of how to proceed``

Answer (score 0):

I guess $H$ is the Heaviside function, i.e. $H=1_{[0,\infty)}$. If so then the Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}(f)$ of $f(t)=H(\pi-t)\sin^2t$ is:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathscr{L}(f)(s)&=&\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)\,dt=\int_0^\pi e^{-st}\sin^2t\,dt=\frac12\int_0^\pi e^{-st}(1-\cos2t)\,dt\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^\pi\left[e^{-st}-\frac{e^{-st+2it}+e^{-st-2it}}{2}\right]\,dt=\frac12\left[-\frac{e^{-st}}{s}-\frac{e^{-st+2it}}{-s+2i}-\frac{e^{-st-2it}}{-s-2i}\right]_0^\pi\\
&=&\frac12\left[\frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{s}+\frac{e^{-\pi s}-1}{s-2i}+\frac{e^{-\pi s}-1}{s+2i}\right]=\frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{2}\left(\frac1s-\frac{2s}{s^2+4}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
i.e.
$$
\mathscr{L}(f)(s)=\frac{(4-s^2)(1-e^{-\pi s})}{2s(s^2+4)} \quad \forall s\in \mathbb{C} \, \mbox{ with }\, \Re s>0
$$

Comment: thanks a lot! but on the last line where do the "i" ' s go on the power of "e" after you do the limits??

Comment: @salam $e^{2i\pi}=e^{-2i\pi}=1$